# datetime match format when month is in string

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Don't know which matching format to use if the month is in string.I have the following date to convert (11-OCT-2017) for which (%d-%m-%Y) isn't working.I'm using Matplotlib.dates module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib.dates` vendors dateutil's parser, so you could use that:

```
>>> import matplotlib.dates
>>> matplotlib.dates.dateutil.parser.parse('11-OCT-2017')
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 11, 0, 0)
```

Or, if you are trying to parse into a matplotlib datenum, then the month format is `%b`:

```
>>> parse = matplotlib.dates.strpdate2num('%d-%b-%Y')
>>> parse('11-OCT-2017')
736613.0
```